# Inflate multiple ConstraintLayout in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, scrollview, android-constraintlayout, android-inflate

I'm developing my first android app and I met some troubles.
In my activity there are the following layouts: ScrollView(ConstraintLayout). 
I made a separate layout(a template, a ConstraintLayout) that I want to inflate in my scrollable list. 
My purpose is to create a list based on my template that I'll inflate.
The result I want to be like the following: ScrollView(ConstrintLayout(ConstraintLayout,ConstraintLayout,...)).

```
ConstraintLayout scrollConstraint = 
(ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.scroll_constraint);
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View newRoute = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scroll, scrollConstraint, false);
        TextView newRouteFrom = (TextView) newRoute.findViewById(R.id.from1);
        if(i==1)
            newRouteFrom.setText("New route");
        scrollConstraint.addView(newRoute);
    }
```

scroll_constraint is my ConstraintLayout ID from ScrollView(ConstraintLayout).
My code is inflating my template(ConstraintLayout) 2 times, but the problem is that those templates are overlapping in exactly the same position.
How can I set a margin between those 2 ConstraintLayouts that I have been added? How can I connect a constraint a constraint from the second ConstraintLayout to his "older" brother?

Comment: It sounds like you would be better off using a LinearLayout inside your ScrollView (since it sounds like you just want the children to appear below each other). Is there some reason you don't want to use LinearLayout?

Comment: Ioi....so that's the magnific difference between ConstraintLayout and LinearLayout. Thank you very much, sir. My problem is solved.

Comment: I don't think the LinearLayout was really a solution. If you want to have something scrollable with multiple of the same views RecyclerView should be the choice.The LinearLayout worked only because you HAVE to add constraints in order for them to be below each other.